# Встреча участников сообщества «Stack Overflow на русском» в Санкт–Петербурге 27 июля 2019 года

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

**Спешу предложить участникам сообщества «Stack Overflow на русском» собраться вместе [у костра] 27 июля 2019 года в Санкт-Петербурге.**

27 июля в Санкт-Петербурге будет проводиться встреча технических сообществ в рамках инициативы «[IT Global Meetup](https://piter-united.ru/)». Встреча будет проходить в Туутари парке.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание!

1. Если вы хотите принять участие, вам необходимо зарегистрироваться на [сайте мероприятия](https://piter-united.ru/). *Участие бесплатное!* При регистрации вам будет предложено выбрать одно из сообществ–участников. Пожалуйста, выберете то, что вам ближе всего. Я выбрал «SPb Python».
2. Я не стал регистрировать наше сообщество как оффлайн–сообщество Санкт–Петербурга, поэтому у нас не будет отдельного стенда и тому подобного. Мы все будем являться обычными участниками мероприятия. С другой стороны, я постараюсь забронировать место для костра (насколько я знаю, они ограничены) и соответствующе подготовиться.
3. Если вы планируете присоединиться, заполните, пожалуйста, [анкету](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bjC4x5K147eNN_foH-dCZ2K7V4nRpO3SePrljuWLUjk/viewform), чтобы я понимал, на сколько человек бронировать место.

Буду крайне рад вас видеть!

Если у вас возникнут какие–либо вопросы, пожалуйста, задайте их мне в комментариях к этому вопросу или в [основном чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

**Обновление**

Опираясь на разговора с организаторами события, требованиями площадки и глядя на ответы в анкете, спешу предложить следующий план действий.

1. Приезжаем на мероприятие во сколько будет удобно.
2. По желанию взаимодействием с ребятами и девчатами из «офлайн» сообществ Санкт-Петербурга.
3. Около пяти часов собираемся в выбранном месте и устраиваем посиделки участниками сообщества Stack Overflow на русском.

Несколько замечаний:

- Для связи предлагаю использовать [основной чат сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).
- Как только получится определиться с местом сбора, я сразу отпишусь в чате и на Мете.
- Вероятно, начать можно раньше пяти, если у вас будет желание.
- Возможность проведения встречи появилась довольно случайно, в тоже время у нас на «складе» не так много сувениров, как хотелось бы. Все же, я очень надеюсь, что для всех, кто заполнит *[анкету](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bjC4x5K147eNN_foH-dCZ2K7V4nRpO3SePrljuWLUjk/viewform)*, найдется футболка нужного размера.
- Я постараюсь захватить что–нибудь съедобное на вечер на всех на свой выбор. Если у вас есть какие–либо предпочтения, пожалуйста, напишите мне об этом [на почту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/?tab=profile) или в [чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).
- Если вы планируете приехать с другом или подругой, пожалуйста, не забудьте взять его / ее с собой, когда пойдете к нашему костру.

Пожалуйста, приезжайте, буду очень рад видеть вас!

Comment: Жаль, что SOru в списке сообществ нету =/

Comment: @Suvitruf В случае, если мы хотим зарегистрироваться сообществом, нам  надо искать докладчиков и делать полную программу лекций. Если у кого–либо есть желание выступить с небольшим докладом, я с радостью зарегистрирую нас отдельным сообществом в следующий раз.

Comment: Может быть @NicolasChabanovsky будет докладчиком? :)

Comment: @Grundy: на тему «Stack Overflow на русском: инструкция по развитию сообщества»?

Comment: @VladD, Grundy слышит нотки сарказма в твоем сообщении :-) Кстати ты можешь приехать на встречу и задать ему вопрос как раз по этой теме :)

Comment: Наконец-то! В этот раз обязательно буду!

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ты будешь там?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ что именно не понимаешь?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ понял :-) удачи с работой)

Comment: @Grundy: В Праге уже задавал.

Comment: @VladD, это было давно и неправда :)

Comment: @Grundy: А с того времени что-то изменилось?

Comment: @VladD, вот и узнаешь :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Дороговато выходит ехать за одним битом информации

Comment: @VladD, так может не за одним ж

Comment: @VladD Добрый день! Буду рад, если вы приедете! Если не получится, ничего  страшного. Как–нибудь попробуем организоваться в Европе, например, в Мюнхене.

Comment: Ребята, кто доехал, приходите, пожалуйста, в зону кемпинга. Жду вас там!

Answer (score 10):

Хотя у нас есть Мета и чаты, встречи в реальном мире — незаменимый атрибут нашего сообщества.

В прошедшие выходные состоялась очередная встреча участников Stack Overflow на русском. Вероятно, это была одна из самых жарких встреч сообщества! … И самая удаленная от города: встреча проходила в Туутари–парк. До мероприятии добрались @Abyx и @kizoso, за что им огромное спасибо! С @kizoso мы встретились днем. Ближе к вечеру пересеклись с @Abyx, и затем за чаем говорили более пяти часов! Обсуждали все: от Java и С++ до главной страницы stackoverflow.com и троллей. Ниже несколько фотографий с мероприятия.

Место проведения встречи.

[image]

Abyx и я греемся на солнышке. =)

[image]

Все разработчики любят оптимизацию! Мы тоже. Оптимизировали поездку домой, привезя дом с собой.

[image]

---

Было очень круто! @Abyx и @kizoso, большое спасибо! С нетерпением жду новых встреч.

Comment: А где логотип StackOverflow на палатке?)
Что, было всего 2 человека? Как то не густо :(

Comment: На столе Steakwine Torrontes? ;-)

Comment: Тебе спасибо за встречу!!! Тоже с нетерпением жду новых!